# How do browsers deal with full caches?

Tags: browser, caching

How do browsers deal with a full cache? Presumably they all make some kind of decision on what to throw away based on file size, expiration time and so on? Anyone know where I can find details? Google just returns a load of pages about manually clearing caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRU_cache

There are several algorythms. Most Recently Used is the simpliest.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms